# Not able to handle different error scenarios in Google Sign in

Tags: android, google-signin

I am using the new Google Sign In to authenticate the users in my application.I am following the official documentation for integration.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

I have generated WEB_CLIENT_ID and **I am able to successfully log in the user**. **But I am facing problems in handling the error scenarios**.

There are 2 primary error scenarios for my application and I want to show different error messages for both of them.

1. When the account picker dialog is displayed, and the user presses back button, then I need to show "User has cancelled the operation".
2. When the user chooses an account from the account dialog picker and he loses his internet connection in the meantime, then I need to show "There is some problem with the network"

The problem I am facing now is that on both the actions the google auth api is returning me a status code 12501. Therefore I am not able to give different error messages based on  status returned by the api. Here is the code I have tried so far.

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_GOOGLE) {
      /* Google SignIn Callback result*/
      if (data == null) {
        return;
      }
      GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
      if (result == null) {
        return;
      }

      if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, get idToken and userID.

      } else {
        // Login not successful.
        Status status = result.getStatus();
        if (status == null) {
          return;
        }

        if (status.isCanceled()) {
          //User canceled the operation
        } else if (status.getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.INVALID_ACCOUNT) {
          //Invalid account
        } else {
          //Generic error
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But every time the google sign in fails, it always go in the else condition. Not able to figure out how to give different error messages for different types of errors?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by adding debug SHA-1 key to firebase.